# jQuery - How to use e.preventDefault(); in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript function :

```
function putVote(trackid, vote) {
}
```

and I call this function trought :

```
<a href="#" onClick="putVote('data1', 'data2')">Link</a>
```

I would like to use `e.preventDefault();` on `putVote()`, but I think I'm wrong in some ways. How can I do it?

Cheers

Comment: You haven't told us *why* you would like to use the function ... however I can say that you'd probably be better off using jQuery to bind your event handler rather than hard-coding it into an attribute.

Comment: You could pass the event to `putVote` and then call `preventDefault()` there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest thing to do would be to `return false` <strike>from the function</strike> in the handler (`return false` would only work in `putVote` if the handler had `return putVote('data1', 'data2)`).

But as Pointy said, a much better technique is to attach the event handler from JavaScript, most easily achieved by using a library/framework such as jQuery or Prototype.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I'd like to use preventDefault :)

Comment: Why no! :) Ok, I'll use return false.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` prevents the event's default action (following a link) but does **not** stop the event from [bubbling up the DOM](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/domtricks2/). Returning `false` does both.

Comment: @josh3736 - that's what I thought originally, but [this fiddle belies that idea](http://jsfiddle.net/cN3Ru/) (unless I'm missing something).

Comment: @Skilldrick: I made a flawed assumption.  Returning `false` from a jQuery bound handler does stop propogation (as well as cancelling the default action), because [jQuery calls `event.stopPropagation()`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.1/src/event.js#L444) if a handler function returns `false`.  However, [inline event handlers](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_early.html) have existed since long before the concept of event bubbling, so returning `false` serves only to prevent the default action.  Of course, no one should use inline event handlers anyway...

Comment: @josh3736 Haha I linked to [that very same line on Twitter earlier](http://twitter.com/#!/skilldrick/status/42966973130358785) :) Yes, I think we're all agreed that inline event handlers are bad. Useful Quirksmode link, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way:

```
<a href="#" onClick="putVote('data1', 'data2'); return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: An old answer but the exact thing I needed.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery.

JS:

```
$("#link").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    putVote('data1', 'data2');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
```

If you're using the latest version of jQuery and the HTML5 doctype.

JS:

```
$("#link").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    putVote($self.data("one"), $self.data("two"));
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="link" data-one="data1" data-two="data2">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the trick with using jQuery-style binding is that you want to be able to pass through element-specific parameters to the handler ("data1", "data2").  The "modern" way to do that would be this:

```
<a href="#" class='data-clickable' data-click-params='["data1", "data2"]'>Link</a>
```

Then, in a "ready" handler (or some other appropriate place), you'd bind your handler:

```
$('a.data-clickable').click(function(e) {
  var elementData = $(this).data('click-params');
  //
  // ... handle the click ...
  //
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The "elementData" variable will end up (in this case, anyway) being an array with two values in it, "data1" and "data2".  You can give JSON-notation values to "data-foo" attributes, and when you fetch the attributes with the jQuery ".data()" method it will automatically decode the JSON for you.